# Override UIViewController's view property

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller

I want to override my `MYViewController : UIViewController`'s `setView:` method, such that, I do not allow some one to set `view`'s property to `nil`.

```
-(void)setView:(UIView*)view {
    if (view == nil)
       //ignore - make no change
    else 
       //default performance
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: what you actually want? implement the setter ?

Comment: Yes. Such that, if `nil` is passed, I should ignore it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling the super class only when you want the default behavior should do the work:

```
-(void)setView:(UIView*)view {
    if (view == nil) {
       //ignore - make no change
    }
    else {
       //default performance
       [super setView:view];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@synthesize view = _view;

-(void)setView:(UIView*)view {
        if (view)
           _view = view;
    }
```

It could be done as simple as this. If `view` is not nil, set the variable.